# How to replace spaces with A[ in emacs

Tags: regex, emacs

I have an input file like this

```
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
```

There are four spaces before all the lines I want to replace.

I want the end result to be:

```
A[line 1
A[line 2
A[line 3
```

(Its funny, so editor doesn't want to display line by line)

I tried `M-x replace-regex ^[]+ -> A\[`, but get error `invalid regex "Unmatched [ or [^"`

I tried `M-x replace-regex ^[]+ -> A[`, but get same error.

Replacing the `[` is a problem.  How to fix this?

Comment: Use the [Force](Ctrl-K) to format your code. )

Comment: Will `M-x replace-regexp ^ -> A[` work, I wonder. )

Comment: @raina77ow - I want to remove the spaces too - but I suppose I can do that separately,  But why did that work?

Comment: Because you have to make Emacs think about regexes, with `replace-string` you'll replace strings, not patterns. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
M-x query-replace-regex RET ^    RET A[ RET
                             ^^^
                          notice the 4 spaces here
```

In your examples you are missing a space inside the character class: `^[ ]+`

Prettier would probably be: `^[[:space:]]+` for every kind of white-space.

Comment: Wow, how dumb was that - I didn't notice that - I just missed typing in the space - and of course it looks like a space might be there.

Comment: @user619818 Happens. Also notice your problem with `replace-string` vs. `replace-regexp` (and the equivalent `query-` functions).

Answer (score 1):

[Rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) give you another way to deal with these issues. [Cua-mode](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.ca/2008/10/emacs-tip-26-cua-mode-specifically.html) provides an even nicer system. To use it, first add the following to your .emacs:

```lisp
(setq cua-enable-cua-keys nil)
(cua-mode)
```

Then, with point at the `*` in the following:

```
*   line 1
    line 2
    line 3
```

Hit `C-enter`, and use the arrow keys (or `C-n` and `C-f`) to move point to:

```
    line 1
    line 2
   *line 3
```

The blanks will all be highlighted. Type `A[` to insert the characters. Then hit `C-w` to delete the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
M-x query-replace-regex RET ^ + RET A[ RET
```

as it's a single kind of characters to replace, brackets or class are not needed